# GetURL variable and display in div

Tags: javascript

this is what I have so far, based on some stuff of I found on the net 
**domain.com/score.html?totalScore=23** how would I get the score variable to pass to the div ID and the mailto link?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getURLParameter(name) {
      return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
    }
    score = getURLParameter('totalScore');
    </script>

    <div id="yourscore"></div>
<a href="mailto:test@test.com?subject=Score:%20">test</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        function getURLParameter(name) {
          return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
        }
        var score = getURLParameter('totalScore');
        document.getElementById("yourscore").innerHTML = score;
            var link = document.getElementById("link");
            link.setAttribute("href", link.getAttribute("href") + "&score=" + score);
    }
</script>

<div id="yourscore"></div>
<a href="mailto:test@test.com?subject=Score:%20" id="link">test</a>
```

Comment: how would I get the score to appear right after `mailto:test@test.com?subject=Score:%20' in the `a href` link?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this personally:

```
function getTotalScore() {
  var search, parts, i, subparts;
  search = window.location.search;
  if (!search) return 0;
  parts = search.substr(1).split('&');
  for (i; i < parts.length; i++) {
    subparts = parts.split('=');
    if (subparts[0] === 'totalScore') {
       return subparts[1];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Then just call `getTotalScore()` and do with it whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of functions to get what you need.  The first gets all of the values and puts them in an array and the second gets the specific value you are looking for.

```
function getQueryStringVals()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1)
    {
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') +   1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            if (hash[1].charAt(hash[1].length - 1) == "#")
            {
                hash[1] = hash[1].slice(0, -1)
            }
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
    }
    return vars;
}

function getQueryStringVar(name)
{
    return getQueryStringVals()[name];
}
```

Comment: There's a window.location.search. :|